# IdentityServer3 & Implicit flow with Javascript - How is client_secret handled

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, identityserver3

In looking for examples/guides on using IdentityServer3 with Javascript web applications (aka SPA), the `Implicit OAuth flow` seems to be the recommended. However, the Implicit flow requires a `client_secret`. How is this accomplished with Javascript and HTML alone since the source code can always be viewed by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit flow does not require a client secret.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight.